# Select Specific Scores Based on a Criteria in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have produced a list based on feature importance using the code below. How do I select the features indexes whose scores are greater than 0.00100?
The code I used is below:

```
importance = rf.feature_importances_
# summarise feature importance
for i,v in enumerate(importance):
    print('Feature: %0d, Score: %.5f' % (i,v))
    
# plot feature importance
pyplot.bar([x for x in range(len(importance))], importance)
pyplot.show()

Feature: 0, Score: 0.00020
Feature: 1, Score: 0.00097
Feature: 2, Score: 0.00122
Feature: 3, Score: 0.00115
Feature: 4, Score: 0.00012
```

I have tried

```
X = importance.loc[:, importance.loc['importance'] <= 0.001]
```

and

```
X = importance[importance['Score'] > 0.00100]
```

but it obviously returns an error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'loc'
```

and

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

respectively.

I believe I can call original columns later once I know the features indexes using:

```
X = X.iloc[:,[0,   3,  18,  27,  31,  32,  39,  67,  90, 114]]
```

Except there is a better way to call them straight away into rather than doing a copy and paste into the iloc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `pandas` you can easily select rows based on a condition. Based on the sample you provided :

```py
importance = np.array([2.04432471e-04, 9.69855344e-04, 1.22306283e-03, 1.15336387e-03, 1.21430735e-04, 3.66518341e-04, 8.84830067e-04,
                       1.82450072e-03, 2.43196633e-03, 4.63633572e-04, 2.12339471e-04, 8.13088621e-04])

df = {
    'Feature': range(len(importance)),
    'Score': importance
}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)

print(df) 
# Sample DataFrame
    Feature     Score
0         0  0.000204
1         1  0.000970
...
11       11  0.000813
```

This line selects only the rows matching the condition "Score greater than 0.00100".

```py
df = df[df['Score'] > 0.00100]

print(df) 
# Output
   Feature     Score
2        2  0.001223
3        3  0.001153
7        7  0.001825
8        8  0.002432
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Titouan L. This would work for a normal pandas dataframe. However the output of importance is an array of the scores.  array([2.04432471e-04, 9.69855344e-04, 1.22306283e-03, 1.15336387e-03,
       1.21430735e-04, 3.66518341e-04, 8.84830067e-04, 1.82450072e-03,
       2.43196633e-03, 4.63633572e-04, 2.12339471e-04, 8.13088621e-04,

Comment: Please edit your post with this information, your question is about pandas column. Having a sample of your data would help

Comment: I have done so, perhaps it should be much clearer now.

Comment: @user15502001 I edited my answer with the provided data, does it seems clearer to you ?

Comment: your answer has been right all along. Thanks. It is clearer. I have up voted it.

Comment: How do I convert the resulting Feature Column into a row so I can use them for iloc X = X.iloc[:,[0,   3,  18,  27,  31,  32,  39,  67,  90, 114]]

Comment: The question is what do you want to achieve with this, you can get the index with `idx = df['Feature'].tolist()` or `idx = df['Feature'].to_numpy()`

Comment: This is Exactly What I Wanted. Thank you, I have learned a lot today. I have used idx = df['Feature'].tolist() and it works perfectly

Comment: @user15502001 You can accept my answer by clicking on the tick under the vote arrows, and accept the edit of your question to make it clearer. I'm glad it worked, have a nice day.